# how to displaying an image import to a folder at the root of my site

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a form that uploads images in a filestore folder that I created at the root of my site. My images are related to products. how to display these images from the product view.
NB: a product can have multiple images.

my entities layer:

```
@Entity

public class Image implements Serializable{
  
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

> ```
> private String filename;    
> @ManyToOne()
> @JoinColumn(name = "produit_id", nullable = false)
> private Produit produit;
>
>    //getters and setters
> }
>
> @Entity
> public class Produit implements Serializable{
> @Id @GeneratedValue
> private Long id;
> private String designation;
> @OneToMany(mappedBy = "produit", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
> private Set<Image> images;
> ```

```
   getters and setters
```

}

my service layer

```
@Service @Transactional public class ImageServiceImpl implements
```

> ```
> IImageService{  
> @Autowired
> private ImageRepository imageRepository;
> Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
> private final Path rootLocation = Paths.get("filestorage");
> @Override
> /* code */ 
> }
>
> @Override
> public Stream<Path> loadFiles() {
>     try {
>         return Files.walk(this.rootLocation, 1)
>                 .filter(path -> !path.equals(this.rootLocation))
>                 .map(this.rootLocation::relativize);
>     }
>     catch (IOException e) {
>         throw new RuntimeException("\"Failed to read stored file");
>     }
> } }
> ```

how to display the image from  product instancewith thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) that is capable of associating content with Spring Data Entities and providing a REST API for managing that content.

Add the following dependencies to your POM (Spring Boot Starters also available):

> pom.xml

```
    <!-- Java API --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configure your file storage:

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/files");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

Associate content with your Produit entity:

```
@Entity
public class Produit implements Serializable{
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String designation;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "produit", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Image> images;
...
```

}

@Entity
   public class Image {
      @ContentId private UUID contentId;
      @ContentLength private Long contentLength;
      @MimeType private String mimeType;
   }

Create a content store (very similar to a Repository interface):

> ImageStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="produitImages")
  public interface ImageStore extends ContentStore<Image,UUID> {
  }
```

And that's it.  The ImageStore is essentially a generic Spring ResourceLoader.  The `spring-content-fs`  dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation so you don't need to worry about implementing it yourself.  Moreover, the `spring-content-rest` dependency will cause Spring Content to also inject an implementation if an `@Controller` that forwards HTTP requests onto the method of the `ImageStore`.

So you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based file service at `/produitImages` that will use your `ImageStore` to retrieve (and store) files in `/path/to/your/files` on your server.

So:

`POST /produitImages/{produitId}/some/image.jpg -F "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/test1.jpg"`

will upload `test1.jpg` and add it to the `produitId1`'s list of images.

`GET /produitImages/{produitId}`

will return the list of images.

`GET /produitImages/{produitId}/images/{contentId}`

will return a specific image.

HTH